# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When i try to run this code in google colab it show module not found error.
This was my code

```
   import pyinputplus as pyip

   response = pyip.inputNum('Enter num: ')
```

Comment: Okay, and why do you think it *should* be able to find the module?

Answer (score 7):

I think you may need to install PyInputPlus in your google colab. You can install in google colab using this `!pip install PyInputPlus`. You need to add "!" before pip statment. That will help you to run terminal commands from your notebook

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to install that module in google colab.
By using:

```py
pip install pyinputplus
```

Then, you can import it by:

```py
import pyinputplus as pyip
```

And then, you will get result like this

[image: img]